# Using Unix command (node.js/lessc in my case) inside python?

Tags: python, django, node.js, less, celery

I am not sure if it is good idea. Here is my requirement.

I have one default less css file and other dynamic less file generated from datasets. Now, I want to compile the above less files to single css file.

So, for this I am thinking of running node.js to do it in background asynchronously with celery. I understand there is python port to compile less to css, but I think node.js is better for this.

Suggestions and ideas please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor ?

Comment: Yes, but it is same as sorl thumbnail - doing everything after user hits the url. This will make it slow, and every new request will load the less file which will hit the database number of times (which I am trying to avoid).

Comment: That's incorrect. After Sorl or Compressor do their job, those files are cached.

Comment: You are right. I haven't used Compressor, but sorl is very slow with remote storages like S3.

Comment: It's relatively slow on the first request, but considerably faster after that. I use Sorl to do thumbnails for images whose URLs are later returned in JSON via REST calls. The images are stored in S3 and served via CloudFront and it's pretty darn fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved this myself using subprocess. Actually, any Unix command can be used this way.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['lessc', '-x', '-'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate(less_content)
```